# making a box2d body move in a spiral motion

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, game-physics, box2d-iphone

How can one make a box2d body move in a spiral motion? I believe it will require applying some force but I am not sure how. I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain joints together using intermediate invisible bodies. Pin a body at the center to the ground with a revolute joint, and a prismatic from that body to the real one. Two joints = two motors = two controllable degrees of freedom.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could explain this further, possibly with a code sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have two forces, a tangential force, and a radial force.

The tangential force accelerates the body around the center.

The radial force accelerates the body towards or away from the center.

```
radialVector = (objectPosition - spiralCenter).normalize();
tangentialVector = radialVector.perpendicularVector();

forceTangential = tangentialForceMagnitude * tangentialVector;
forceRadial = radialForceMagnitude * radialVector;
force = forceTangential + forceRadial;
object.applyForce(force);
```

The specific values for your force magnitudes will determine the behaviour of the spiral; things like wether it's an inward or outward motion, and how fast.

I answered a related question about making a whirlpool/vortex: [SO: How to create whirlpool/vortex effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952561/2669591)